# Visualize Graphviz svg graphs in html canvas with events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas

I'm generating graphs using graphviz on the backend, for example the following dot file

```
digraph G {

        # list of nodes
        9 [label="9", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="9"]
        1 [label="1", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="1"]
        2 [label="2", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="2"]
        6 [label="6", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="6"]
        8 [label="8", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="8"]
        14 [label="14", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="14"]
        5 [label="5", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="5"]
        7 [label="7", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="7"]
        10 [label="10", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="10"]
        12 [label="12", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="12"]
        0 [label="0", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="0"]
        3 [label="3", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="3"]
        4 [label="4", color ="blue", shape="box", class="even", id="4"]
        11 [label="11", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="11"]
        13 [label="13", color ="blue", shape="box", class="odd", id="13"]

        # list of edges
        0 -> 1 [color ="red", class="left", id="0_1"]
        0 -> 2 [color ="red", class="right", id="0_2"]
        1 -> 4 [color ="red", class="right", id="1_4"]
        3 -> 8 [color ="red", class="right", id="3_8"]
        5 -> 11 [color ="red", class="left", id="5_11"]
        2 -> 5 [color ="red", class="left", id="2_5"]
        3 -> 7 [color ="red", class="left", id="3_7"]
        4 -> 9 [color ="red", class="left", id="4_9"]
        6 -> 14 [color ="red", class="right", id="6_14"]
        2 -> 6 [color ="red", class="right", id="2_6"]
        5 -> 12 [color ="red", class="right", id="5_12"]
        6 -> 13 [color ="red", class="left", id="6_13"]
        1 -> 3 [color ="red", class="left", id="1_3"]
        4 -> 10 [color ="red", class="right", id="4_10"]
}
```

becomes to following SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.49.1 (20210923.0004)
 -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="566pt" height="260pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 566.00 260.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 256)">
<title>G</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-256 562,-256 562,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- 9 -->
<g id="9" class="node odd">
<title>9</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="198,-36 144,-36 144,0 198,0 198,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="171" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">9</text>
</g>
<!-- 1 -->
<g id="1" class="node odd">
<title>1</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="234,-180 180,-180 180,-144 234,-144 234,-180"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="207" y="-158.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">1</text>
</g>
<!-- 3 -->
<g id="3" class="node odd">
<title>3</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="126,-108 72,-108 72,-72 126,-72 126,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="99" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">3</text>
</g>
<!-- 1&#45;&gt;3 -->
<g id="1_3" class="edge left">
<title>1&#45;&gt;3</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M180.58,-143.88C166.59,-134.81 149.22,-123.55 134.11,-113.76"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="135.82,-110.69 125.52,-108.19 132.01,-116.57 135.82,-110.69"/>
</g>
<!-- 4 -->
<g id="4" class="node even">
<title>4</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="234,-108 180,-108 180,-72 234,-72 234,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="207" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">4</text>
</g>
<!-- 1&#45;&gt;4 -->
<g id="1_4" class="edge right">
<title>1&#45;&gt;4</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M207,-143.7C207,-135.98 207,-126.71 207,-118.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="210.5,-118.1 207,-108.1 203.5,-118.1 210.5,-118.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 2 -->
<g id="2" class="node even">
<title>2</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="378,-180 324,-180 324,-144 378,-144 378,-180"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="351" y="-158.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">2</text>
</g>
<!-- 6 -->
<g id="6" class="node even">
<title>6</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="378,-108 324,-108 324,-72 378,-72 378,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="351" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">6</text>
</g>
<!-- 2&#45;&gt;6 -->
<g id="2_6" class="edge right">
<title>2&#45;&gt;6</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M351,-143.7C351,-135.98 351,-126.71 351,-118.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="354.5,-118.1 351,-108.1 347.5,-118.1 354.5,-118.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 5 -->
<g id="5" class="node odd">
<title>5</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="486,-108 432,-108 432,-72 486,-72 486,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="459" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">5</text>
</g>
<!-- 2&#45;&gt;5 -->
<g id="2_5" class="edge left">
<title>2&#45;&gt;5</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M377.42,-143.88C391.41,-134.81 408.78,-123.55 423.89,-113.76"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="425.99,-116.57 432.48,-108.19 422.18,-110.69 425.99,-116.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 14 -->
<g id="14" class="node even">
<title>14</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="342,-36 288,-36 288,0 342,0 342,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="315" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">14</text>
</g>
<!-- 6&#45;&gt;14 -->
<g id="6_14" class="edge right">
<title>6&#45;&gt;14</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M342.1,-71.7C338,-63.73 333.05,-54.1 328.51,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="331.48,-43.4 323.8,-36.1 325.26,-46.6 331.48,-43.4"/>
</g>
<!-- 13 -->
<g id="13" class="node odd">
<title>13</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="414,-36 360,-36 360,0 414,0 414,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="387" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">13</text>
</g>
<!-- 6&#45;&gt;13 -->
<g id="6_13" class="edge left">
<title>6&#45;&gt;13</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M359.9,-71.7C364,-63.73 368.95,-54.1 373.49,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="376.74,-46.6 378.2,-36.1 370.52,-43.4 376.74,-46.6"/>
</g>
<!-- 8 -->
<g id="8" class="node even">
<title>8</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="54,-36 0,-36 0,0 54,0 54,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">8</text>
</g>
<!-- 12 -->
<g id="12" class="node even">
<title>12</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="486,-36 432,-36 432,0 486,0 486,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="459" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">12</text>
</g>
<!-- 5&#45;&gt;12 -->
<g id="5_12" class="edge right">
<title>5&#45;&gt;12</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M459,-71.7C459,-63.98 459,-54.71 459,-46.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="462.5,-46.1 459,-36.1 455.5,-46.1 462.5,-46.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 11 -->
<g id="11" class="node odd">
<title>11</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="558,-36 504,-36 504,0 558,0 558,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="531" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">11</text>
</g>
<!-- 5&#45;&gt;11 -->
<g id="5_11" class="edge left">
<title>5&#45;&gt;11</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M476.8,-71.7C485.6,-63.14 496.38,-52.66 506,-43.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="508.68,-45.58 513.41,-36.1 503.8,-40.57 508.68,-45.58"/>
</g>
<!-- 7 -->
<g id="7" class="node odd">
<title>7</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="126,-36 72,-36 72,0 126,0 126,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="99" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">7</text>
</g>
<!-- 10 -->
<g id="10" class="node even">
<title>10</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="270,-36 216,-36 216,0 270,0 270,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="243" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">10</text>
</g>
<!-- 0 -->
<g id="0" class="node even">
<title>0</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="306,-252 252,-252 252,-216 306,-216 306,-252"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="279" y="-230.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">0</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="0_1" class="edge left">
<title>0&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M261.2,-215.7C252.4,-207.14 241.62,-196.66 232,-187.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="234.2,-184.57 224.59,-180.1 229.32,-189.58 234.2,-184.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;2 -->
<g id="0_2" class="edge right">
<title>0&#45;&gt;2</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M296.8,-215.7C305.6,-207.14 316.38,-196.66 326,-187.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="328.68,-189.58 333.41,-180.1 323.8,-184.57 328.68,-189.58"/>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;8 -->
<g id="3_8" class="edge right">
<title>3&#45;&gt;8</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M81.2,-71.7C72.4,-63.14 61.62,-52.66 52,-43.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="54.2,-40.57 44.59,-36.1 49.32,-45.58 54.2,-40.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;7 -->
<g id="3_7" class="edge left">
<title>3&#45;&gt;7</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M99,-71.7C99,-63.98 99,-54.71 99,-46.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="102.5,-46.1 99,-36.1 95.5,-46.1 102.5,-46.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;9 -->
<g id="4_9" class="edge left">
<title>4&#45;&gt;9</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M198.1,-71.7C194,-63.73 189.05,-54.1 184.51,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="187.48,-43.4 179.8,-36.1 181.26,-46.6 187.48,-43.4"/>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;10 -->
<g id="4_10" class="edge right">
<title>4&#45;&gt;10</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M215.9,-71.7C220,-63.73 224.95,-54.1 229.49,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="232.74,-46.6 234.2,-36.1 226.52,-43.4 232.74,-46.6"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The SVG text serves no other purpose to me than to denote (x,y) coordinates of where to place the shapes. I would like to transform this svg data to be displayed in an html5 `canvas` and also retain the ability to make events happen based on clicking on the nodes via their `class` and `id` parameters as well as have the ability to zoom in and out and pan.

Is this possible and if so how can I do it easily?

Answer (score -2):

well it is pretty easy actually
see this example I wrote just for you

```js
var id=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]

id.forEach( e=> {
document.getElementById(e).addEventListener('click',()=>{
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = e + " element clicked";
})
} );
```

```html
PLEASE CLICK ON any element
<p id='output' > </p>
<svg width="566pt" height="260pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 566.00 260.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 256)">
<title>G</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-256 562,-256 562,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- 9 -->
<g id="9" class="node odd">
<title>9</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="198,-36 144,-36 144,0 198,0 198,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="171" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">9</text>
</g>
<!-- 1 -->
<g id="1" class="node odd">
<title>1</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="234,-180 180,-180 180,-144 234,-144 234,-180"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="207" y="-158.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">1</text>
</g>
<!-- 3 -->
<g id="3" class="node odd">
<title>3</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="126,-108 72,-108 72,-72 126,-72 126,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="99" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">3</text>
</g>
<!-- 1&#45;&gt;3 -->
<g id="1_3" class="edge left">
<title>1&#45;&gt;3</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M180.58,-143.88C166.59,-134.81 149.22,-123.55 134.11,-113.76"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="135.82,-110.69 125.52,-108.19 132.01,-116.57 135.82,-110.69"/>
</g>
<!-- 4 -->
<g id="4" class="node even">
<title>4</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="234,-108 180,-108 180,-72 234,-72 234,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="207" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">4</text>
</g>
<!-- 1&#45;&gt;4 -->
<g id="1_4" class="edge right">
<title>1&#45;&gt;4</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M207,-143.7C207,-135.98 207,-126.71 207,-118.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="210.5,-118.1 207,-108.1 203.5,-118.1 210.5,-118.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 2 -->
<g id="2" class="node even">
<title>2</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="378,-180 324,-180 324,-144 378,-144 378,-180"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="351" y="-158.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">2</text>
</g>
<!-- 6 -->
<g id="6" class="node even">
<title>6</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="378,-108 324,-108 324,-72 378,-72 378,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="351" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">6</text>
</g>
<!-- 2&#45;&gt;6 -->
<g id="2_6" class="edge right">
<title>2&#45;&gt;6</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M351,-143.7C351,-135.98 351,-126.71 351,-118.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="354.5,-118.1 351,-108.1 347.5,-118.1 354.5,-118.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 5 -->
<g id="5" class="node odd">
<title>5</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="486,-108 432,-108 432,-72 486,-72 486,-108"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="459" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">5</text>
</g>
<!-- 2&#45;&gt;5 -->
<g id="2_5" class="edge left">
<title>2&#45;&gt;5</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M377.42,-143.88C391.41,-134.81 408.78,-123.55 423.89,-113.76"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="425.99,-116.57 432.48,-108.19 422.18,-110.69 425.99,-116.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 14 -->
<g id="14" class="node even">
<title>14</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="342,-36 288,-36 288,0 342,0 342,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="315" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">14</text>
</g>
<!-- 6&#45;&gt;14 -->
<g id="6_14" class="edge right">
<title>6&#45;&gt;14</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M342.1,-71.7C338,-63.73 333.05,-54.1 328.51,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="331.48,-43.4 323.8,-36.1 325.26,-46.6 331.48,-43.4"/>
</g>
<!-- 13 -->
<g id="13" class="node odd">
<title>13</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="414,-36 360,-36 360,0 414,0 414,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="387" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">13</text>
</g>
<!-- 6&#45;&gt;13 -->
<g id="6_13" class="edge left">
<title>6&#45;&gt;13</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M359.9,-71.7C364,-63.73 368.95,-54.1 373.49,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="376.74,-46.6 378.2,-36.1 370.52,-43.4 376.74,-46.6"/>
</g>
<!-- 8 -->
<g id="8" class="node even">
<title>8</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="54,-36 0,-36 0,0 54,0 54,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">8</text>
</g>
<!-- 12 -->
<g id="12" class="node even">
<title>12</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="486,-36 432,-36 432,0 486,0 486,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="459" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">12</text>
</g>
<!-- 5&#45;&gt;12 -->
<g id="5_12" class="edge right">
<title>5&#45;&gt;12</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M459,-71.7C459,-63.98 459,-54.71 459,-46.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="462.5,-46.1 459,-36.1 455.5,-46.1 462.5,-46.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 11 -->
<g id="11" class="node odd">
<title>11</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="558,-36 504,-36 504,0 558,0 558,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="531" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">11</text>
</g>
<!-- 5&#45;&gt;11 -->
<g id="5_11" class="edge left">
<title>5&#45;&gt;11</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M476.8,-71.7C485.6,-63.14 496.38,-52.66 506,-43.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="508.68,-45.58 513.41,-36.1 503.8,-40.57 508.68,-45.58"/>
</g>
<!-- 7 -->
<g id="7" class="node odd">
<title>7</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="126,-36 72,-36 72,0 126,0 126,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="99" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">7</text>
</g>
<!-- 10 -->
<g id="10" class="node even">
<title>10</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="270,-36 216,-36 216,0 270,0 270,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="243" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">10</text>
</g>
<!-- 0 -->
<g id="0" class="node even">
<title>0</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="blue" points="306,-252 252,-252 252,-216 306,-216 306,-252"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="279" y="-230.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">0</text>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;1 -->
<g id="0_1" class="edge left">
<title>0&#45;&gt;1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M261.2,-215.7C252.4,-207.14 241.62,-196.66 232,-187.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="234.2,-184.57 224.59,-180.1 229.32,-189.58 234.2,-184.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 0&#45;&gt;2 -->
<g id="0_2" class="edge right">
<title>0&#45;&gt;2</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M296.8,-215.7C305.6,-207.14 316.38,-196.66 326,-187.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="328.68,-189.58 333.41,-180.1 323.8,-184.57 328.68,-189.58"/>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;8 -->
<g id="3_8" class="edge right">
<title>3&#45;&gt;8</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M81.2,-71.7C72.4,-63.14 61.62,-52.66 52,-43.3"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="54.2,-40.57 44.59,-36.1 49.32,-45.58 54.2,-40.57"/>
</g>
<!-- 3&#45;&gt;7 -->
<g id="3_7" class="edge left">
<title>3&#45;&gt;7</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M99,-71.7C99,-63.98 99,-54.71 99,-46.11"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="102.5,-46.1 99,-36.1 95.5,-46.1 102.5,-46.1"/>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;9 -->
<g id="4_9" class="edge left">
<title>4&#45;&gt;9</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M198.1,-71.7C194,-63.73 189.05,-54.1 184.51,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="187.48,-43.4 179.8,-36.1 181.26,-46.6 187.48,-43.4"/>
</g>
<!-- 4&#45;&gt;10 -->
<g id="4_10" class="edge right">
<title>4&#45;&gt;10</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M215.9,-71.7C220,-63.73 224.95,-54.1 229.49,-45.26"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="232.74,-46.6 234.2,-36.1 226.52,-43.4 232.74,-46.6"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is this being displayed in an html5 canvas though? (that is my goal) And, is it is possible to pan and zoom?

Comment: yes just click expand snippet and it will open in full page so you will see it is displaing in html canvas plus this is an example with sample evants you can have your own events on each item this way including pan and zoom or application of new css styles, etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing the pan/zoom capabilities and I don't believe that is in an html5 canvas object https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: oops sorry I missunderstood you :'D

Comment: But Y would you need a canvas wher job is getting done just fine with this approach as well.

Comment: with this approach as well

Comment: another approach would be to declare an empty div or section and inside of that div having multiple div each contining the above generated code and all done by javascript. for example
<div id="graphs">
</div>
and in javascript
var div = " <div id = "graph-1" class = ""> generated svg </div>"
document.getElementById('graphs').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',div);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).